# Distinct on multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I wish to find out the count of distinct rows in a MySQL DB.

```
id | val1 | val2 | val3

1  |  1   |  1   |  1
2  |  1   |  1   |  1
3  |  2   |  2   |  2
4  |  2   |  2   |  2
```

On the table above the query would return

```
val1 | val2 | val3 | count
1    |   1  |  1   |   2 
2    |   2  |  2   |   2
```

Does anyone know a reasonably efficient way of achieving this in MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause for this:

```
SELECT val1, val2, val3, count(*) AS count
FROM mytable GROUP BY val1, val2, val3
```

## [*See this fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0807d/4)

Comment: @marabutt and Spechal it is really nice tool.